# How can I make inheritance without third object shim?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I try to understand OOP in JavaScript.
I want to create object Person and Worker. Worker inherits Person. I wrote code:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.grow = function () {
    this.age++;
    console.log('Person grows, new age ' + this.age);
};

function Worker(name, age, position) {
    // How to call parrent constructor Person?
    this.position = position;
}

Worker.prototype = Person.prototype;
Worker.constructor = Worker.prototype.constructor;

Worker.prototype.promote = function () {
    console.log('Worker ' + this.name + ' became Senior ' + this.position);
};

Worker.prototype.grow = function () {
    this.promote();
    // How to call parrent method grow?
};

var workerObj = new Worker('Ben', 39, 'engineer');

workerObj.grow();
```

But in JS variable assignment works by reference and expression `Worker.prototype = Person.prototype;` doesn't get result and method grow in Worker overrides method grow in Person and I will not be able to get access to parent method.

I know that I need to use third object. But is there way to inherit without third object?

Comment: *"But is there way to inherit without third object?"* Well, yes, like you have it, but it also has the drawbacks you mentioned. You can't have both.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the functions' `.prototype` properties to the same object essentially makes them the same class, as you've noticed. **What you really need, is for Person.prototype to be an object that inherits from Worker.prototype. But you need to do this without calling the Person constructor**, since that leave some side effects back in the prototype chain (they aren't significant in the case you mention, but they could be significant in other cases). So `Worker.prototype = new Person();` isn't an ideal solution for you.

**Object.create() works for this**. Among other things, this function can be used to create an object that inherits from another, *without* calling any constructors. For the situation you're talking about, it would look like this:

```
Worker.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Worker.prototype.constructor = Worker;
```

Object.create doesn't work in older versions of IE, and a total polyfill isn't available due to engine limitations. But **there are polyfills for Object.create which work well enough to enable this kind of subclassing**, so browser support need not be an issue.

I typically wrap this up in a function, so that once I've defined my subclass and superclass, I can express the relation without much extra rigamarole. You could do that like this:

```
Object.subclass = function (sub, sup) {
    sub.prototype = Object.create(sup.prototype);
    sub.prototype.constructor = sub;
}

Object.subclass(Worker, Person); // "class Worker extends Person"
```

Comment: Thank you, I understood my mistake with Person constructor. But how can I get access to Person.prototype.grow  in Worker.prototype.grow ?

Comment: If you're talking about having `Worker.prototype.grow()` call `Person.prototype.grow()` you'd do something like `Person.prototype.grow.call(this/*, arg1, arg2, ...*/)`.

Comment: All you said is correct, but doesn't really address the OP's question/problem. `Object.create` still creates an object.

Answer (score 0):

I make inheritance in javascript like this :

```
var c_Parent = function () {

};

var c_Child = function () {

    c_Parent .call(this);
};

c_Child.prototype = new c_Parent();
c_Child.prototype.constructor = c_Child;
```

So in you case :

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.grow = function () {
    this.age++;
    console.log('Person grows, new age ' + this.age);
};

function Worker(name, age, position) {
    this.position = position;

    Person.call(this, name, age);
}

Worker.prototype = new Person();
Worker.prototype.constructor = Worker;


Worker.prototype.promote = function () {
    console.log('Worker ' + this.name + ' became Senior ' + this.position);
};

Worker.prototype.grow = function () {
    this.promote();
    Person.prototype.grow.call(this);
};

var workerObj = new Worker('Ben', 39, 'engineer');

workerObj.grow();
```

Comment: You want call child.grow and parent.grow ?

Comment: Yes. I could call Person.prototype.grow.call(this) in Worker.prototype.grow, but i don't like it.

Comment: This code work as you want without create a "sub" object, what is wrong for you ?